# issues using .css() to style height

Tags: jquery, css, plugins

I'm doing a tutorial on basic jQuery plugins. I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out why my code isn't altering the height of my `<p></p>`.

The exercise says to create a plugin that will set the height of the passed in elements without using `.height()`.

While the mini plugin below won't change the height, if I simply flip the `height` property within `.css()` to something like `margin` it works perfectly.

What am I missing?

```
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($, window, document, undefined) {
            $.fn.setHeight = function(hgt) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).css('height', hgt);
                });
            };
        })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
    <script>
        $("p").setHeight(200)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works fine in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2c4FE/) when running in the latest version of Chrome. I added a border color to the `p` tag so you can see the height increase. What browser are you using?

Comment: did you try $(this).css({'height':hgt})

Comment: @jsshah: Using that variation of `.css()` was added in jQuery 1.9 and OP is using jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Some browsers may complain if a unit is missing. Did you try 200px instead of just 200?

Comment: @Sinan, yes, tried that also.

Comment: @jsshah: Seem OP has update the script to jQuery 1.9 (it was 1.7.1 when I copied OPs code into the fiddle) but using that `.css()` variation should be no different. But worth a try anyway.

Comment: @jsshah, yes, still testing it but hasn't made a difference. The really odd/frustrating part is that if I simply swap the height property in .css() for margin the code works fine.

Comment: @KMcA: What I don't get is that when I run your code in the fiddle I linked in the latest version of Chrome, FF and IE9 it works and sets the height of the `p` tag to `200px`. Do you have any other CSS which might be over-writing the `height`?

Comment: Works well in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2c4FE/1/), too.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - I think he may have overridden the `display` property in his actual implementation (not the fiddle) - this is the only thing that would explain the `.css()` method having no effect, if jQuery is, in fact, working

Comment: No, I haven't overwritten it. There is no css in my code at all except for the jQuery method.

Comment: What browsers have you tried?

Comment: I just posted my entire code in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bASWb/. Height doesn't work here either, but margin and padding do.

Comment: How are you deciding that the height is wrong without displaying a border? I added a border property in your fiddle, and it looks like it's working. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bASWb/2/

Comment: @Barmer, you're right. I'm so, so, so sorry for the mistake. I see it now. Please forgive me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that I would do here:

First, I would make sure to explicitly set the `display` property of the `p` tag to `display:inline-block` or `display:block`, just in case this was modified elsewhere.

Second, and this is the more important part, change the height value, `hgt`, that you pass to the plugin to be a string with a unit (`px`, `pt`, `em`, etc.) appended to it.

Good luck and let me know if you have any further questions/problems! :)

**UPDATE**

Let's start by simplifying the plugin. Try this and let me know what the result is:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.fn.setHeight = function(hgt) {
        $(this).css('height', hgt);
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bASWb/1/).

Comment: Why would margin, padding, etc. not need to have px specified? Still need to try your suggestions.

Comment: Tried adding px and both display properties but still no luck. If you look at the jQuery source, px is actually set by default which is why I left blank.

Comment: Ultimately, if you have overridden the `display` property, then `margin` and `padding` will still work, but `height` will not. jQuery may do some work to inherit units. (Note: I removed my original comment because, though accurate, I do not know if it is relevant to this situation, in that I think there may be other technologies allowing the units to be left out for certain properties)

Comment: Okay, I will keep looking. Before I continue, have you tried testing with `!important` for the `display` property, just in case your CSS is still being overridden?

Comment: Nevermind that last - I just saw your other comment on the OP

Comment: I just posted my entire code in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bASWb/. Height doesn't work here either, but margin and padding do.

Comment: Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: And are you havign this issue in both?

Comment: Check my post - I simplified the plugin and added an updated version of your fiddle. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yes it did. And it is very basic jQuery. If it is still not working for you, then there is something else happening. Is it working in the fiddle but not on the actual website?

Comment: I'm so, so, so sorry. I see by increasing the border now it's working. What a stupid beginner mistake... sorry to waste your time. Please forgive me.

Comment: Not a problem, at all. We have all been there and sometimes, especially when first starting with a new technology, it can be tough to see little things like that. It's what we are here for. Good luck :)